# How to export select query data into excel file using Oracle query?

Tags: excel, oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which generates reports for a particular day. Is there any query where in Oracle with export it into excel? I dont want to manually export it. Am using oracle developer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `SPOOL` and you can not directly write to `.xls` file, You need to write data to `.csv` file and open it in `Excel`.

```
set sqlformat csv
spool d:\your_file.csv
select * from your_table;
spool off;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Oracle SQL devloper:

Export Query Output to Excel in Oracle SQL Developer without spooling:

```
Step 1: Run your query. To start, you'll need to run your query in SQL Developer. ...
Step 2: Open the Export Wizard. ...
Step 3: Select the Excel format and the location to export your file. ...
Step 4: Export the query output to Excel.
```

For example:

[image]

If you are not using wizard then other way to do this is using below commands:

```
@export on;
@export set CsvColumnDelimiter=";";
@export set ShowNullAs="";
@export set filename="/home/xxx.csv";


select * from XX_TABLE;

@export off;
```

Comment: I didnt want to use the Wizard.

Comment: @Suyash i have added other way to export in csv